# does not route to page using ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, jsp

Request is not redirected to login page. Before that i uses **ui-router** then it redirect request to details page. Then i shifted to ng-route. But hear problem is that it does not route to login page.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

     $routeProvider

    .when('/:category', {
        templateUrl: "views/home.jsp",
        controller:"recommendationController"
    })
    .when('/:allP', {
        templateUrl: "views/home.jsp",
        controller:"allProducts"
    })
    .when('/:category/:isbn',{
        templateUrl:"views/details.jsp",
        controller:"DetailsController"
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: "views/contact.jsp"
     })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: "views/login.jsp",
        controller:"LoginController"
    })

    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: "views/signup.jsp"
    })
    .when('/resetPassword', {
        templateUrl: "views/forget.jsp"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:"/:category"
    })

});
```

Comment: why change to ngroute? ui-router is so cool.

Comment: did u forgot enable html5mode?

Comment: If i understand well, your problem is that you use a redirection to "/login" but it redirects to "/:category/:isbn", could you show us more code please ?

Comment: @levi : I got same problem with ui-router so i change to ngroute.

Comment: @Aliz : Exact which code do you want? Login form code or Category code.

Comment: All you think which may be useful to us to help you. More you give, better we understand ;)

Comment: Finally i solved the problem using ui-router, Basically my concept was not clear about it. Thank you friends for your help.